# Executing commands in "gVim Easy"

Tags: gvim

I have installed the windows version of gVim, which comes with "gVim Easy", a version of VIM configured to make it very easy to use by constandly being on insert mode, however most of the power of the editor is lost this way, because there is no way to get into command mode.

Is there a way to get into command mode using "gVim Easy" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"gVim Easy" is referred to in the documentation as "evim". I don't know how one is supposed to find that out since there are no :help topics that include the string "easy". The :help topics that include "evim" include

```
:help evim-keys
```

which says at the bottom:

> One hint: If you want to go to Normal mode to be able to type a sequence of
>   commands, use CTRL-L. |i_CTRL-L|

So the answer is: type Ctrl-L.

Comment: Who would have thought it would be so easy. Thank you :)